# How to add mapbox access token with Angular-plotly.js

Tags: angular, plotly, mapbox

I am trying to use graph and map with plotly.js. I am using angular-ploty.js for that. Graph is working fine but when I try to use map,that time its showing error of mapbox access token not defined.I have mapbox access token but dont know how to add it in Angular.Please help me for this small issue.

Here is my HTML component code.

```
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>
```

Here is component.ts code.

```
public graph = {
   data: [{
    type: 'scattermapbox',
    lat: ['45.5017'],
    lon: ['-73.5673'],
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
      size: 14
    },
    text: ['Montreal']
  }],
  layout : {
    autosize: true,
    hovermode: 'closest',
    mapbox: {
      bearing: 0,
      center: {
        lat: 45,
        lon: -73
      },
      pitch: 0,
      zoom: 5
    },
  },
 mapboxaccesstoken: 'Entered mapbox access token here'
 };
```

I am using `PlotlyViaWindowModule`.